# Laravel. After call toArray(), the value in attribute property is changed

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to get address data from customer table.
But my address data includes country, city and address.
Therefore I want to make address field to country, city and address three fields.

The following is my code

```php
    $result = Customer::select('customers.address AS country', 'customers.address AS city', 'customers.address')->get();
    dump($result[0]); // First result

    $temp = $result->toArray();
    dd($temp[0]); // Second result
```

[image]

The following is my questions:

1. Why is country and city changed in attribute property? I didn't do anything.

---

It is magic. I change [country] to [countrys] and [city] to [citys].
The following is my new code

```
$result = Customer::select('customers.address AS countrys', 'customers.address AS citys', 'customers.address')->get();
        dump($result[0]);

        $temp = $result->toArray();
        dd($temp[0]);
```

The countrys and citys didn't change in attribute property anymore.

[The output picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyXIR.jpg)

Can anyone tall me why? It's really strange.

Comment: I think you are using `casts` to country and city.

Comment: Hello! Could you provide the version of the Laravel framework you are using for future reference, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per Laravel Documenation:

> The `toArray` method **converts the collection into a plain PHP array**. If the collection's values are `Eloquent models`, the models will also be converted to arrays

Aslo

> `toArray` also converts all of the collection's nested objects that are
>   an instance of `Arrayable` to an array. If you want to get the raw
>   underlying array, use the all method instead.

[Laravel -> Collection -> toArray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-toarray)

Comment: But my customers table has many fields, like id, name,...
I just want to get address data from customers table.
And then reset country, city and address. 
After that call toArray() to get array, use excel function to output excel file that has country, city and address data.

Answer (score 0):

The following is my code to resolve my question [Why is country and city changed in attribute property?]

```
// Add the following code to Customer model
public function setCountryAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['country'] = $value;
}

public function getCountryAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['country'];
}

public function setCityAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['city'] = $value;
}

public function getCityAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['city'];
}
```